# Foreach cycle in PHP, bad assign of key

Tags: php, foreach

OK, I admit this is a dull question but I cant find mistake.

So my code:

```
$this->table = array (
          "š" => "&scaron;",
          "Š" => "&Scaron;",
          "ý" => "&yacute;",
          "Ý" => "&Yacute;",
          "á" => "&aacute;",
          "Á" => "&Aacute;",
          "í" => "&iacute;",
          "Í" => "&Iacute;",
          "ú" => "&uacute;",
          "Ú" => "&Uacute;"
        );

$this->keyword = "š Č ú";

foreach ($this->table as $key => $value) {
                echo "key: ".$key." value ".$value." ";
                $this->keyword = str_replace($key, $value, $this->keyword);
            }
```

So I want to replace specials chars in var keyword according values in array, but this aint working. Output from this part of script is:

key: š value š
key: Š value Š
key: ý value ý
...

What am I doing wrong? Why is value `$key`  same as `$value`?

Comment: Because `&scaron;` represents `š` in browser. Use `echo htmlspecialchars($value);` to see the real value

Comment: Oh, I thought that problem is elsewhere. Thank you. Shame on me.

Comment: Tip: Always view *the raw output* of your script. In the browser that's View Source.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`htmlentities`](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php) on `$value`, otherwise the entity (e.g. `&uacute;`) will be rendered by the browser.

```
...
echo "key: ".$key." value ".htmlentities($value)." ";
...
```